# create if conditional based on css properties -- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How do you find if css properties are set in a certain way? For example how do you find if an element has a css property of `background-color:#ff0000;`? Or if the element has a certain width etc...

Comment: Do you mean you want to find properties set directly on the element using the `style` attribute, or you want to find the effective value of the element considering all CSS rules and the cascade?

Comment: @WilliamGreen what you want is getComputedStyle. Look it up using google. If you use an external stylesheet then element.style.prop won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to determine it for all css properties including visibility:
    this works for properties set in a external css file, internal embedded styles, or inline styles!
    ***Note: the document MUST be loaded before executing the script!***

I have tested this out and it works with css rules set in inline, embedded, and external.

html:

```
        <div id="element" onload="test();">div content</div>
```

css:

```
        #element
        {
        visibility:hidden;
        }
```

javascript:

```
        function test()
        {
            var element = document.getElementById('element');
             if(element.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
            alert('hidden');
            }
           if(element.style.visibility == 'visible')


    {
    alert('visible');
         {
    if(element.style.visibility == 'collapse')
    {
    alert('collapsed');
    }
    if(element.style.visibility == 'initial')
    {
    alert('initial');
    }
    if(element.style.visibility == 'inherit')
    {
    alert('inherit');
    }
        }
```

I have used this before.

Comment: Did you test this? It won't work. The CSS rule does **not** affect `element.style`.

Comment: it seemed to work in another program I made. However just now in response to your comment I did some testing and the browser is giving me errors! I don't know why since it's the same code I used before and it worked! I don't get it!

Comment: ah that's it the document has to load first! :-)

Comment: That's it the document must be loaded before the script executes otherwise it will think that the element doesn't exist!

Comment: The basic problem remains that the CSS rule will not do anything with or to `element.style.visibility`. It will start off, and remain, an empty string. Your little program is likely to display "visible", because the `element.style.visibility == 'hidden'` condition will be false. It might be nice to put up a fiddle or something to show your approach and validate that it works.

Comment: I tried jsfiddle just now (thanks for the suggestion! I just got an account today). Unfortunately jsfiddle (in my particular situation) messed with the point I was trying to prove by automatically adding an window.onload! Therefor I didn't want to post it since it won't work unless the whole document has loaded.